# docker containers cannot reach internet in bridge network mode

Tags: linux, networking, dns, docker

**TL;DR**
*How can I fix the bridge docker0 to be able to reach internet from my containers when in network mode bridge?*

---

There was a power outage a couple of weeks ago that apparently destroyed a server network configuration, and for some time, the DHCP server wasn't assigning the correct IP to the machine. I managed to fix that by configuring the network using `netplan` (which I cannot assure was done before the power outage, it was managed by another team).

However, `docker` containers are not being able to reach internet when network mode is `bridge`.

From the host, I can `ping google.com` and DNS resolution works fine. Everything else seems to be working too. However, when I start a container (for instance:  `docker run -it --rm python:3.6.1 /bin/bash`) `ping` doesn't work anymore.

So here it goes the couple of things I have checked:

1. `ping` within the container does not work:

`ping google.com` just hangs:

```
root@85deb9b2ae95:/# ping google.com
^C
```

`ping 8.8.8.8` lost all packages:

```
root@85deb9b2ae95:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
^C--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

2. `/etc/resolv.conf` in the docker container looks ok:

```
root@85deb9b2ae95:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

(It's the same as the host's one)

3. `docker network inspect bridge` looks fine to me:

```
my_user@my_host:~$ docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "ba15db4d28312e1e7147704d4b04ed12d5acf3ffc03d5308a61e88171ff21b59",
        "Created": "2022-09-30T12:04:54.442845526Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "85deb9b2ae951810887faf6a89b1980bd4ae35d6a61a1639982a3a6558f8100f": {
                "Name": "strange_fermi",
                "EndpointID": "181fede143c82cee3aff9feec8bfff10daf9fbcbd1e70a69bd99ee51f28ed5e4",
                "MacAddress": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

4. `ifconfig` looks fine to me (it's `RUNNING` because the container is running):

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 xx::xx:xx:xx:xx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 660  bytes 36996 (36.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 263  bytes 26836 (26.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

5. I don't see anything weird in the output of `networkctl`:

```
alberto_perdomo@builder02:~$ networkctl
IDX LINK        TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP      
  1 lo          loopback carrier     unmanaged  
  2 enp67s0f0   ether    routable    configured 
  3 enp67s0f1   ether    no-carrier  configuring
  4 wlp70s0     wlan     no-carrier  unmanaged  
 60 docker0     bridge   routable    unmanaged
```

Apart from the iface `enp67s0f1` "configuring" (which I think might have something to do with the way I configured the network using netplan).

6. Kernel route looks fine:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp67s0f0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp67s0f0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp67s0f0
```

7. `ip route` looks fine:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp67s0f0 proto static 
172.17.0.0/24 dev enp67s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp67s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.32
```

8. `iptables` look ok to me:

```
my_user@my_host:~$ sudo iptables --list --table nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

9. These are my current docker networks:

```
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
ba15db4d2831   bridge    bridge    local
938ad254f4d2   host      host      local
72ca52dfdedb   none      null      local
```

Finally, if I run the container in host mode (for instance:  `docker run -it --rm --net=host python:3.6.1 /bin/bash`), DNS resolution works.

It cannot be as simple as appending `--net=host` to my docker commands because this server run some CI/CD pipelines that should be able to reach internet, resolve domain names and so on and so forth.

So basically, the main question is **how can I fix the bridge docker0 to be able to reach internet from my containers when in network mode bridge?**

I have tried several things among which it was restoring docker, reinstalling docker, removing the `docker0` iface and forcing docker to create it again.

Any help, feedback or comments on how to solve or troubleshoot this will be much appreciated!

Comment: Steps 6. and 7. show the host has no default route. So I wonder how you get the ping from host working? Or is the host actually running a VM which runs Docker rather than running Docker directly?

Comment: @A.B sorry, I didn't post the full response. There are default routes, I only posted the part related to docker0. Fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The narrower route:

> ```
> 172.17.0.0/24 dev enp67s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
> ```

takes precedence over the route:

> ```
> 172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
> ```

So IP packets intended for addresses between 172.17.0.2 and 172.17.0.254 are routed through `enp67s0f0` instead of `docker0`.

For example when container *strange_fermi* tries to `ping 8.8.8.8`, while its own outgoing packets are probably processed (unless the host set [`rp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.15#n1489) to 1 for [SRPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2)) reply packets coming back sent to host's 192.168.1.32 address (because they were SNAT-ed) are then de-SNAT-ed by *iptables* rules set by Docker as expected, to reach back 172.17.0.2.

But this new destination 172.17.0.2 is routed through interface `enp67s0f0` instead of `docker0` and lost: container can't communicate.

The immediate fix is to remove this address:

```
ip address delete 172.17.0.1/24 dev enp67s0f0
```

And of course, the configuration having done this must also be amended accordingly.

Comment: sharp eye! thank you so much!