# kernel routing tables config does not persist after reboot

Tags: linux, networking, netplan

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1745422/docker-containers-cannot-reach-internet-in-bridge-network-mode) regarding some faulty kernel routing tables configuration that I had in one of my machines due to an unexpected power outage. That event left the machine with a messed up network (`netplan` btw) config and I did my best to leave it functional.

Finally, I was able to find out a solution for the issue that I asked in the aforementioned question, but the fix is not persistent over restarts. That is, every time I restart the machine, I have to manually run:

```
# ip address delete 172.17.0.1/24 dev enp67s0f0
```

I have looked for ways to make this persistent but none of them seem to work and I don't exactly know how I can keep this permanent. Any feedback will be highly appreciated!

Comment: That's not an iptables config though. And the easiest way to make "undo something" persistent is to make "do nothing" persistent, no?

Comment: Oops, sorry if I'm mixing terms here. I'm fairly new to Linux networking. It makes sense but not sure what's the opposite rule of that one.

Answer (score 2):

Deletion is already permanent, because addresses are not *stored* permanently in `ip addr` – the interface always starts with zero addresses on every boot; some software has to re-add them every time. So you have to remove the address *from the place that is causing it to be re-added.*

Most of the time, that would be your regular network configuration tool – Netplan, or systemd-networkd, or ifupdown (aka /etc/network/interfaces); maybe a stray DHCP client (dhcpcd or dhclient). In your specific case though, it may also come from Docker configuration which is using the wrong interface.

Comment: I'll check this and reach back. Thanks for the explanation!